# Getting two same values with array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to get all different values.

The code that i have works fine, until one point...

```
$array_for_19_2=[
["A 1","A 1","A 1","A 2","A 3","A 2","A 1","A 3","A 2","A 1","A 3","A 3","A 2","A 1","A 2"],
["A a","A a","A c","A a","A c","A c","A c","A a","A a","A c","A c","A a","A a","A a","A c"],
["A X","A Y","A Z","A Z","A Z","A Y","A X","A X","A X","A X","A Z","A Z","A X","A Z","A Y"],
["1 a","1 b","1 a","1 a","1 b","1 c","1 b","1 c","1 b","1 a","1 a","1 c","1 b","1 a","1 a"],
["2 a","2 a","2 a","2 a","2 a","2 a","2 a","2 b","2 b","2 a","2 a","2 b","2 a","2 b","2 b"],
["3 b","3 c","3 b","3 c","3 a","3 b","3 c","3 b","3 b","3 b","3 c","3 c","3 a","3 c","3 b"],
["a X","a X","a Z","a Y","a Z","a X","a Y","a Z","a Z","a Z","a X","a X","a Y","a Y","a Z"],
["b Z","b Z","b X","b Z","b Z","b Z","b Z","b X","b Y","b Y","b X","b X","b Y","b Y","b Z"],
["c Y","c Y","c Y","c Y","c Z","c Z","c X","c X","c Z","c Y","c Y","c X","c Z","c Y","c X"],
["1 Z","1 Z","1 X","1 Y","1 X","1 Z","1 X","1 Y","1 Y","1 Z","1 X","1 Z","1 Y","1 Y","1 Y"],
["2 X","2 X","2 Y","2 Z","2 Y","2 X","2 X","2 Z","2 Y","2 Y","2 Y","2 X","2 Y","2 X","2 X"],
["3 X","3 X","3 Y","3 X","3 Y","3 Y","3 Y","3 X","3 Z","3 X","3 X","3 Y","3 Y","3 X","3 Y"]];

foreach (array_count_values($array[$i]) as $key => $value) {
                if(strrpos($key, "A")===0 && is_numeric(substr($key,2)))
                {$keycount1++;}
                else if(strrpos($key, "A")===0 && !is_numeric(substr($key,2))){
                array_push($lettersarray, substr($key, 2)); 
                }
                $probabilty=round(($value/count($array[$i])),2);
                echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br/>Probability: $probabilty<br/>"; 
                $names=str_replace(' ', '', $key);
                $newarray[$key]=$probabilty;

        }
```

It works fine with all arrays, except the one that starts "A X". I get result like:

```
    A 1 - 6 
Probability: 0.4
A 2 - 5 
Probability: 0.33
A 3 - 4 
Probability: 0.27

A a - 8 
Probability: 0.53
A c - 7 
Probability: 0.47

**A X - 5 
Probability: 0.33
A Y - 3 
Probability: 0.2
A Z - 5 
Probability: 0.33
A Z - 1 
Probability: 0.07
A X - 1 
Probability: 0.07**

1 a - 7 
Probability: 0.47
1 b - 5 
Probability: 0.33
1 c - 3 
Probability: 0.2

2 a - 10 
Probability: 0.67
2 b - 5 
Probability: 0.33

3 b - 7 
Probability: 0.47
3 c - 6 
Probability: 0.4
3 a - 2 
Probability: 0.13

a X - 5 
Probability: 0.33
a Z - 6 
Probability: 0.4
a Y - 4 
Probability: 0.27

b Z - 7 
Probability: 0.47
b X - 4 
Probability: 0.27
b Y - 4 
Probability: 0.27

c Y - 7 
Probability: 0.47
c Z - 4 
Probability: 0.27
c X - 4 
Probability: 0.27

1 Z - 5 
Probability: 0.33
1 X - 4 
Probability: 0.27
1 Y - 6 
Probability: 0.4

2 X - 7 
Probability: 0.47
2 Y - 6 
Probability: 0.4
2 Z - 2 
Probability: 0.13

3 X - 7 
Probability: 0.47
3 Y - 7 
Probability: 0.47
3 Z - 1 
Probability: 0.07
```

why do I get the same values twice?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Could you clarify?

Comment: i'll try. I have an array, and I need to get all unique values, and how many of them there are, and then count a probability of each unique value. By the way, some code does some other things

Comment: Code works fine for me, see https://eval.in/211439

Comment: Thanks Paul for trying it. I see, it works, but somewhy it doesnt for me... Letters are all the same (I mean no other languages letters), but i get the wrong result...

Comment: this might help u.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php#95713 it will return count of all values

Comment: Doesnt work @webdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

This will return count of all values.

```
$res = array_icount_values ($array);
echo '<pre>';print_r($res);

function array_icount_values($arr, $lower = true) {
    $arr2 = array();
    if (!is_array($arr['0'])) {
        $arr = array($arr);
    }
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $v2) {
            if ($lower == true) {
                $v2 = strtoupper($v2);
            }
            if (!isset($arr2[$v2])) {
                $arr2[$v2] = 1;
            } else {
                $arr2[$v2]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr2;
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same result